# Interactive Gundam using only Matplotlib

Tags: python, game, animation, matplotlib

The code below plots a background image (sky) and then a Gundam sprite using Matplotlib. It also creates 4 buttons with obvious purposes.

The `Gundam` class stores 2 plotted image objects by the name `.img_object` and `.img_riflemode_object`. By default the code plots the `.img_object` (set to `visible = True`), and the `.img_riflemode_object` (set to `visible = False`). The rifle mode sprite (`.img_riflemode_object`) will be visible (for period of 10 frames only) only when the user click the "beam rifle" button. The changing visibility if the sprites are also handled inside the `animate` function (handles the period of visibility of rifle mode sprite and also the thrust).

The object of `Gundam` class also stores the object of `Thruster`, which stores 4 sprites of:

- `thrust_up.img` (visible by default),
- `thrust_down.img` (only visible when user press "down" button),
- `thrust_right.img` (only visible when user press "right arrow" button),
- `thrust_left.img` (only visible when user press "left arrow" button).

The "down", "right", and "left" thrust will be visible only for period of 5 frames (managed in `animate` function).

Finally, the object of `RifleEffect` class also attached to the object of `Gundam` class. It stores the sprite of beam rifle and only appear when user press "beam rifle" (visible for period of 10 frames, same as gundam rifle mode sprite).

Changing the position of sprites is handle by the `.extent` method of each class.

The sprite files can be downloaded in this repo: https://github.com/anbarief/matplotlib-ex/tree/master/Examples/Gundam%20Interactive%20Animation

---

**Question**

- How to make the code to be more efficient for large number of data plotted?
- How to make the design to be more readable and sustainable for more complex/further development?

---

**Demo:**

[image]

---

**The code:**

```
import math
SIN = math.sin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.widgets import Button


def adjust_extent(extent):
    return [extent[0]+0.5, extent[1]+0.5, extent[3], extent[2]]

def inbound(pos):
    if (0 <= pos[0] <= 200) and (0 <= pos[1] <= 200):
        return True
    return False

def animate(frame):
    x,y = gundam.pos
    gundam.set_pos(x, y + 0.25*SIN(frame))

    if gundam.thruster.state != 'up':
        if gundam.thruster.anim_count == 5:
            gundam.thruster.anim_count = 0
            gundam.thruster.visible('up')
            gundam.thruster.state = 'up'
        else:
            gundam.thruster.anim_count += 1

    if gundam.img_riflemode_object.get_visible():
        if gundam.anim_count == 10:
            gundam.anim_count = 0
            gundam.visible()
        else:
            gundam.anim_count += 1


class Gundam(object):
    def __init__(self, fname, fname_rifle, ax, pos):
        self.fname = fname
        self.fname_rifle = fname_rifle
        self.anim_count = 0
        self.ax = ax
        self.fig = self.ax.figure
        self.pos = pos
        self.thruster = Thruster(ax, [pos[0]-10, pos[1]-5])
        self.rifle_effect = RifleEffect(ax, pos)
        self.img_matrix = plt.imread(fname)
        self.img_object = ax.imshow(self.img_matrix)

        self.img_riflemode_matrix = plt.imread(fname_rifle)
        self.img_riflemode_object = ax.imshow(self.img_riflemode_matrix, visible=False)

        #calculate dimension:
        default_extent = adjust_extent(self.img_object.get_extent())
        self.dim = default_extent[1]-default_extent[0], default_extent[3]-default_extent[2]

        default_extent = adjust_extent(self.img_riflemode_object.get_extent())
        self.dim_riflemode = default_extent[1]-default_extent[0], default_extent[3]-default_extent[2]
        ##
        
        self.img_object.set_extent(self.extent())
        self.img_riflemode_object.set_extent(self.extent(mode='riflemode'))

    def extent(self, mode='normal'):
        dim = self.dim
        if mode == 'riflemode':
            dim = self.dim_riflemode
        return [self.pos[0]-dim[0]/2, self.pos[0]+dim[0]/2, \
                self.pos[1]-dim[0]/2, self.pos[1]+dim[1]/2]

    def visible(self, mode='normal'):
        if mode == 'riflemode':
            self.img_object.set_visible(False)
            self.img_riflemode_object.set_visible(True)
            self.rifle_effect.visible(True)
        else:
            self.img_object.set_visible(True)
            self.img_riflemode_object.set_visible(False)
            self.rifle_effect.visible(False)

    def set_pos(self, x, y):
        #The Rifle mode sprite, the Thrust, and also the Beam effect
        #follows the Normal mode Gundam sprite position. 
        self.pos = [x,y]
        self.img_object.set_extent(self.extent())
        self.img_riflemode_object.set_extent(self.extent(mode='riflemode'))
        self.thruster.set_pos(x, y)
        self.rifle_effect.set_pos(x, y)

    def move_right(self, event):
        self.pos[0] += 3
        if not inbound(self.pos):
            self.pos[0] += -3
        self.set_pos(*self.pos)
        self.thruster.move_right()
        self.rifle_effect.set_pos(*self.pos)

    def move_left(self, event):
        self.pos[0] += -3
        if not inbound(self.pos):
            self.pos[0] += 3
        self.set_pos(*self.pos)
        self.thruster.move_left()
        self.rifle_effect.set_pos(*self.pos)

    def move_up(self, event):
        self.pos[1] += 2
        if not inbound(self.pos):
            self.pos[1] += -2
        self.set_pos(*self.pos)
        self.thruster.move_up()
        self.rifle_effect.set_pos(*self.pos)

    def move_down(self, event):
        self.pos[1] += -2
        if not inbound(self.pos):
            self.pos[1] += 2
        self.set_pos(*self.pos)
        self.thruster.move_down()
        self.rifle_effect.set_pos(*self.pos)

    def beam_rifle(self, event):
        self.visible(mode='riflemode')
        

class Thruster(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, pos):
        self.ax = ax
        self.fig = self.ax.figure
        self.pos = pos
        self.state = 'up'
        self.anim_count = 0

        self.img_matrix = {'up': plt.imread('thrust_up.png'), 'down': plt.imread('thrust_down.png'), \
                           'right': plt.imread('thrust_right.png'), 'left': plt.imread('thrust_left.png')}
        self.img_object = {'up': ax.imshow(self.img_matrix['up'], visible = True), 'down': ax.imshow(self.img_matrix['down'], visible=False), \
                           'right': ax.imshow(self.img_matrix['right'], visible = False), 'left': ax.imshow(self.img_matrix['left'], visible =False)}
        
        #calculate dimension:
        self.dim = {} 
        for img in self.img_object.values():
            default_extent = adjust_extent(img.get_extent())
            self.dim[img] = default_extent[1]-default_extent[0], default_extent[3]-default_extent[2]
            img.set_extent(self.extent(img))
        ## 

    def visible(self, direction):
        for key in self.img_object.keys():
            if key == direction:
                self.img_object[key].set_visible(True)
            else:
                self.img_object[key].set_visible(False)
        
    def extent(self, img):
        return [self.pos[0]-self.dim[img][0]/2, self.pos[0]+self.dim[img][0]/2, \
                self.pos[1]-self.dim[img][1]/2, self.pos[1]+self.dim[img][1]/2]

    def set_pos(self, x, y):
        if self.state in ('up', 'right'):
            self.pos = [x-10,y-5]
        if self.state == 'left':
            self.pos = [x+4, y]
        if self.state == 'down':
            self.pos = [x-10, y]
        for img in self.img_object.values():
            img.set_extent(self.extent(img))

    def move_right(self):
        self.visible('right')
        self.anim_count = 0
        self.state = 'right'
        
    def move_left(self):
        self.visible('left')
        self.anim_count = 0
        self.state = 'left'

    def move_up(self):
        self.visible('up')
        self.anim_count = 0
        self.state = 'up'

    def move_down(self):
        self.visible('down')
        self.anim_count = 0
        self.state = 'down'

        
class RifleEffect(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, pos):
        self.ax = ax
        self.fig = self.ax.figure
        self.pos = pos
        self.anim_count = 0

        self.img_matrix = plt.imread('explosion_beam_long.png')
        self.img_object = ax.imshow(self.img_matrix, visible=False)
        
        #calculate dimension:
        default_extent = adjust_extent(self.img_object.get_extent())
        self.dim = default_extent[1]-default_extent[0], default_extent[3]-default_extent[2]
        self.img_object.set_extent(self.extent)
        ##

    def visible(self, boolean):
        self.img_object.set_visible(boolean)

    @property
    def extent(self):
        return [self.pos[0]-self.dim[0]/2, self.pos[0]+self.dim[0]/2, \
                self.pos[1]-self.dim[1]/2, self.pos[1]+self.dim[1]/2]

    def set_pos(self, x, y):
        self.pos = [x+370, y-10]
        self.img_object.set_extent(self.extent)


dt = 0.2
times = [0 + dt*i for i in range(1000)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_xlim([0, 200])
ax.set_ylim([0, 200])

mat = plt.imread("sky_bg_small.png")
ax.imshow(mat)

fname = "ms_08_normal.png"
fname_rifle = "ms_08_aim.png"
gundam = Gundam(fname, fname_rifle, ax, [100,100])

#creating the Button(s) GUI
ax_right = fig.add_axes([0.9, 0.5, 0.05, 0.075])
btn_right = Button(ax_right, '>')
btn_right.on_clicked(gundam.move_right)

ax_left = fig.add_axes([0.9 - 0.05, 0.5, 0.05, 0.075])
btn_left = Button(ax_left, '<')
btn_left.on_clicked(gundam.move_left)

ax_up = fig.add_axes([0.9 - 0.1/2, 0.5 + 0.075, 0.1, 0.075])
btn_up = Button(ax_up, 'up')
btn_up.on_clicked(gundam.move_up)

ax_down = fig.add_axes([0.9 - 0.1/2, 0.5 -0.075, 0.1, 0.075])
btn_down = Button(ax_down, 'down')
btn_down.on_clicked(gundam.move_down)

ax_beam_rifle = fig.add_axes([0.9 - 0.15/2, 0.5 -3*0.075, 0.15, 0.075])
btn_beam_rifle = Button(ax_beam_rifle, 'beam rifle')
btn_beam_rifle.on_clicked(gundam.beam_rifle)
##

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = times, repeat=True, interval = 50)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's certainly interesting, though `matplotlib` isn't the easiest way to write games in Python. What is the motivation to do this?

Comment: @Reinderien just for experience and to update CV.